# A matrix representation of linear transformation in R3

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $E = \langle e_1, e_2, e_3 \rangle$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. 
> Suppose $T: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3} $ is a linear transformation which satisfies: $ [T]^{E}_{E}  = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 9 \\\ 2 & 4 & 8 \\\ 3 & 3 &  3 \end{pmatrix} $
>
> Is there a basis $\beta$ of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ which satisfies:
> $ [T]^{\beta}_{\beta}  = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4 & 8 \\\ 1 & 3 & 9 \\\ 3 & 3 &  3 \end{pmatrix} \space $ ?

The only fact I could've come up so far is that we can take $I_3$, perform the corresponding row replacement and have:

$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $

then we have, $ A[T]^{E} _ {E} = [T]^{\beta} _ {\beta}$. However I struggle to see how to proceed from there.

(To make clear, if $\alpha, \gamma$ are some basis of vector space $V$ s.t $dimV = n$ and $T:V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation then $[T]^{\alpha} _ {\gamma} e_j = [T(a_j)]_{\gamma} $ where $a_j$ is the $j$ vector at the basis $\alpha = \langle a_1, ..., a_n \rangle$)

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are the matrices of the same linear map in different basis, then they should have the same determinant. There is an easy way to check that this is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks, why is that true though?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ represent the same linear map if and only if there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A = P^{-1} B P$. Or altenativaly via the definition of the determinant of a linear map and a matrix.